# dismissViewControllerAnimated issue with navigation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

This is my application code , which i used for selecting the image picker ,when image picks i want to dismiss the current view controller, Since its not dismissing from current view controller at the dismissal time of image picker itself ,

```
 -(IBAction)selectExitingPicture
 {
      self.imagePicker = [[GKImagePicker alloc] init];
      self.imagePicker.cropSize = CGSizeMake(296, 300);
      self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
      self.imagePicker.resizeableCropArea = YES;
      [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
 }
 -(void)imagePicker:(GKImagePicker *)imagePicker pickedImage:(UIImage *)image
 {
      appDel.im=image;
      [self hideImagePicker];
 }
 - (void)hideImagePicker
 {
      [self.imagePicker.imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
                            [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewCont animated:YES ];
                         }];
 }
```

Please help me to solve this issue, What code should i want add further

Answer (score 0):

You should use this line to dismiss the PickerController :

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

You may call this line in both delegate methods :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

and

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
```

Comment: yeah i have updated , now the view not navigating after finishing the dismissal

Comment: did you also add your code to push the new UIViewController after dismissing the pickerController? If yes, you can also try to push it using 'performSelector:withObject:afterDelay' giving a delay of 0.1f.

Comment: you should put all your updated code because I have tested on my end and it work quite well, even without the performSelector.

Comment: OK so I see you are using a library 2 crop your image after selecting it. You should follow the example here : https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker/blob/master/GKImagePicker/ViewController.m

Then if you need to push another viewController after the crop, you have to do it in : `- (void)imagePicker:(GKImagePicker *)imagePicker pickedImage:(UIImage *)image`

Comment: that only i have did by calling `[self hideImagePicker];`

Answer (score 0):

.h file
         int flg;

.m file

```
    viewDidLoad
     flg=0;


  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      if(flg==1) {
           [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            flg=0;
      }
  }

  - (void)hideImagePicker
   {

       [self.imagePicker.imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

   }

  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
        self.imgView.image = image;
        flg=1; 
       [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```

Comment: Its not working mate, When i cancel in image picker ,Application gets crashed

Comment: you have to put cancel method for it.   - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker

Comment: `[self presentViewController:self.imagePicker.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];` its a custom class,since that image picker dismiss by the `-(void)hideImagePicker` method

Comment: see my edited answer you habe to write didFinishPickingImage: method

Comment: set flg=0; on viewWillappear